# Why were these three questions migrated, then closed?

Tags: discussion

[In the 1993 Battle of Mogadishu, were the US's Humvees bullet-proof?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61115)
[In the Vietnam War, which front-line US soldiers were issued pistols?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61116)
[In the Battle of la Drang, who's this unconscious Huey helicopter pilot?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61117)

These are historical questions of fact that can be definitely answered. Thus why were they migrated to Movies, then closed?

Comment: Minutae isn’t history. History is contextual and narrative.